# Should questions with little information due to classified nature be asked?

Tags: discussion

Recently I found out about the fact that in NET June, CASC is planning to [launch an experimental space plane](https://nextspaceflight.com/launches/details/3952). This caught me off guard as I had previously never seen/heard anything about it and was considering asking a question here about it. However then I saw

> We have little information about this launch, and about the spacecraft, which has no name.[Source](https://nextspaceflight.com/launches/details/3952)

Any question regarding the shuttle would likely just stipulate no answers or have answers of "we don't know," so is there any purpose in asking a question relating to the topic? (This also extends to other heavily classified projects)

Note: This [meta question](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348/no-sense-of-humor-when-people-ask-obviously-classified-questions) does discuss classified topic questions, but in regards to humorous answers to that question, not whether the question should be asked.

Comment: related and currently unanswered [(What's best to do about questions that might not be answerable for a few months?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1407/12102)

Answer (score 6):

AFAIK it's on-topic so is allowed.

The only issue is that, like a lot of questions to which the answers are not known ("What are the details of this SpaceX device exactly?") it will probably attract bad speculative unsourced answers.

But you never know. Somebody might write a good answer.